# Passing a temporary derived object to base reference

Tags: c++

```
class B {};
class D : public B{};


f(B& x);
f(D());
```

I noticed (I have copy constructor with log information) that only `Base` copy constructor was called. Is it correct and why?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The function signature of `f(B&)` has no return type, and calling it with `f(D())` doesn't work either as it tries to bind a temporary `D()` to an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

A non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to an rvalue, so your example program fragment is ill-formed.

If we fixed the example to use a const lvalue reference, there would be no copies involved of either class instance.

So, in conclusion: No, it is not correct.